# Duplicate content error results instead of a 404 page

Tags: htaccess, codeigniter

My current URL is: `www.example.com/category/we-developer/` However, if any user mistakenly adds extra characters after the `/`, for example, `www.example.com/category/we-developer/fgggfgg`, it should take him to a `404` page. But instead, the user is again viewing the previous page (`www.example.com/category/we-developer/`)

This is why Google is showing it as a duplicate page. What I wish is that instead of opening the same page, the user would be taken to a '404` page.

Can you advise on how to do this? Note that my site is using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Google won't make links up. If you've not linked to www.example.com/category/we-developer/fgggfgg anywhere, then Google won't try to index it. Google follows links, it doesn't guess URIs.

Comment: You need to fix the problem in your CMS code. I assume CodeIgniter has a routing system similar to Symfony 2. You need to check the routing rules there.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily serve up a 404.

If users are actually linking to your content this way, then changing your application to serve up a 404 will result in a loss of backlinks. i.e. All links to `www.example.com/category/we-developer/fgggfgg` will be lost. Instead, I would make use of  [canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/category/we-developer/" />
```

This will tell Google that the original content is on `http://www.example.com/category/we-developer/` and that said content can be accessed via multiple URLs.

This way, you fix the duplicate content issue without losing out on previously-posted links.

Comment: But however, if a URI does not exist on the domain, it should still serve a 404 error, _not_ resolve to the parent page. The URI `fgggfgg` does not exist.

Comment: If users are clicking on said link and content is being served, with no 404 being thrown, then the link does exist, despite the fact that it is duplicate content.

Comment: The link exists in Google's index - it doesn't actually exist on the website so a 404 error should be served. The website isn't configured correctly to serve 404's if the page doesn't exist.

Comment: OP said that it does exist on the website. That the content from the page `www.example.com/category/we-developer/` is being shown. This makes sense, seeing as many frameworks view the third part of the URL as a controller function parameter.

Comment: No - it doesn't exist - the OP has not created a page with URI `fgggfgg` - they are saying that they can type absolutely anything after `www.example.com/category/we-developer/` such as `www.example.com/category/we-developer/23985y6pw98t98wet9w8e` and it will still resolve to the parent path. That doesn't mean it exists, it means their website is not configured correctly.

Comment: If Google considers it to be a page, then it does exist. A page either exists or it does not. Whether or not it **should** exist is a completely question. As it stands, the page does exist and according to OP, there are inbound links pointing towards it. Returning a 404 now is fine, **if** he's OK with the fact that these links will be lost.

Comment: That's backwards logic. Anyone could link to any URL on any domain that does not exist, just because the link then exists on the web doesn't mean it exists in the website. To prevent lots of random (non-existent) URL's being indexed in Google from people making typo's when linking to web pages, it should be handled by serving a 404 status to inform a) the end user that the page does not exist and b) the search engine so that they don't index (because if they did, it would be duplicate content - the point of this question).

Comment: Doesn't matter if the links are lost (if there any) because they point to a non-existent location. Hence why the website needs to be configured correctly to serve a 404 'page not found so don't both looking here again' error.

Comment: That's why I said that he should use canonical URLs. With canonical URLs, he doesn't have to worry about being penalized for duplicate content, nor are the pages likely to be indexed. Plus he gets to keep his inbound links. Everyone wins.

Comment: That isn't the correct handling though for this situation. Why serve a canonical URL for pages that don't exist when you could serve a 404 and be done with it. Otherwise you'll have to write a lot of needless code to say if these children don't exist, serve parent canonical URL otherwise for all children that do exist, serve the current URL canonical. It's just a waste of time.

Comment: @zigojacko Because throwing a 404 could result in a loss of backlinks. Also, because he's using a framework, it doesn't require a lot of code. Just construct the URL and insert it into the view.

Comment: Why do you want keep backlinks that point to a non existent page. If any are of any significant value (and genuine typo's), then they should be 301 redirected to the correct URL.

Comment: Because they currently point to a page that, for all intents and purposes, does exist.

Comment: @zigojacko if the "junk" url returns 200 (and content), technically it exists; your point is correct regarding "it should not exist", but it is there.

Comment: The page still doesn't exist in the website / in the actual CMS - that's my point. Yes the URL resolves (returns 200 OK) but that was my point, it should return a 404 error because the OP has not created the page and there is no actual content to serve at the URL because it doesn't exist in the system.

Comment: I guess both of you are right: it's better to fix the application, 301 redirect those identified mistaken urls, in case you don't have such redirect at least implement canonical for avoiding duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter's code sounds actually quite good for usability - if it can't find a page, it takes you to the category where that page is likely to be rather than returning nothing.

Pages you have knowingly changed the URL of are better 301d rather than 404d so they go to exactly the right page.

The only potential duplicate content problem here is if Google accidentally index the wrong version of a page.  They could only do that if any links are pointing to the wrong URL.  It is not going to be treated any more a new page than the fact that every site on the web can have new duplicate pages by appending a parameter to the URL.  They are usually pretty good at recognising which URL is canonical.  If not, help them out with a canonical tag.

(If you really need to change the routing rules, then a Google tells me they are set at `application/config/routes.php` - though make sure you follow any override guidelines instead of hacking at core code)